# Any "natural" topology on fractional field of a topological ring?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $R$ be a topological integral domain. Let $K=\mathrm{Frac} R$. Is there any "natural" topology on $K$? Actually, since $K$ can be regarded as a quotient of $R\times R$ quotient some equivalence relation, so maybe we can equip $R\times R$ with the product topology, and that induces topology on $K$?

In particular, suppose $R$ has the complete $(p)$-adic topology, where $(p)$ is the ideal $pR$, then what does the induced topology on $K$ look like?

I did came across an old question, 
[Is $k(\!(x,y)\!)$ a topological field?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226660/is-k-x-y-a-topological-field)
and so, it seems that it is quite a confusing question to topologize a fractional field?

Comment: You could check out Bourbaki, TG.III.6 Exercice 27 for some results on this.

Comment: @FredRohrer Do you mean General topology, Chapter 3 (topological groups), section 6 (topological groups with operators.....)? There are only 26 exercises for that section....no Exercise 27....

Comment: @guestguest: I refer to the French edition from 1971 which contains said exercise.

Comment: @FredRohrer You're right (I have it), strange it disappeared in the English edition.

Comment: Not strange at all. The English translation is based on the 1966 edition.

Comment: A difference between $A=k[[x]]$ and $A=k[[x,y]]$ ($k$ field) is that in the second case $A$ is not open in its fraction field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As said Fred Rohrer, exercise 27 exists in the French edition and seems to answer the question of the MO. Let 
$$
s_{frac}\ :\ R\times R'\to Frac(R)
$$ 
($R'=R\setminus \{0\}$) be the canonical surjection. The "quotient field equivalence" $\equiv_{frac}$ on $R\times R'$ is that given by $s_{frac}$ i.e. 
$$
(a,p)\equiv_{frac} (b,q) \Longleftrightarrow s_{frac}(a,p)=s_{frac}(b,q) \Longleftrightarrow aq=bp\ .
$$
As a matter of fact, if the product topology on $R\times R'$ passes to quotient as a topology on $Frac(R)$ compatible with its field structure and inducing the given one on $R$, it is the *finest* of all topologies (a) compatible with the field structure (b) inducing the given topology on $R$. Bourbaki's exercise gives a sufficient condition ($\equiv_{frac}$ is an open equivalence relation on $R$) so that this occured (i.e. the quotient topology on $Frac(R)$ induces the given topology on $R$).

**Update** In the general case $S^{-1}R$ can also be constructed as the direct limit $\lim_\rightarrow R_t$ (thanks to David Handelman) where 
$$
R_t:=(t^{\mathbb{N}})^{-1}R\ ;\ t^{\mathbb{N}}:=\{t^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
$$ 
the direct system being preordered by divisibility
$$
s\prec t\Longleftrightarrow (\exists u\in S)(t=us)
$$
one can check that the two constructions (by usual quotient or by direct limit) solve the same universal problem (algebraic **and** topological i.e. in the category of topological rings), their topology is therefore the same. The topology of $(t^{\mathbb{N}})^{-1}R$ could be easier to describe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if $\mathbb Z$ is discrete, what topology do we get for $\mathbb Q$?  Coarser than the usual topology?

Comment: @GeralEdgar I might be wrong, but you get the quotient topology of $\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus\{0\})$ by the action of $\mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus \{0\}$, which if I'm not mistaken is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: So "coarser" means what?  Fewer open sets?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar II didn't make the exercise yet (let me until thursday). They seem to say that this topology is extreme. Let me see.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar They say "moins fine" which means coarser (in the usual sense : less open sets) than all the topologies (1) being compatible with the field structure of $Frac(R)$ and (2)  inducing on $R$ the given topology.

Comment: thanks. I will try to find the book and find the exercise...

Comment: I guess we need to know what is the "quotient field equivalence". The action of $\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ on $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\})$ is this: $(a,b) \mapsto (ka,kb)$.  In the discrete topology, all orbits are open sets, so the quotient topology is again discrete.  Which is not coarser than the usual topology on $\mathbb Q$. So that can't be it.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Since $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus\{0\})$ is discrete, its quotient by *any* equivalence relation is discrete.