# Topological fraction rings and fields

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, big-list

Linked to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263323/any-natural-topology-on-fractional-field-of-a-topological-ring/263336#263336) 
and as a sequel to my answer of it.

Let $R$ be a topological (commutative, unital) ring and set $S$ be a submonoid of $(R,\times,1_R)$.
Let 
$$
s_{frac}\ :\ R\times S\to S^{-1}R
$$ 
be the canonical surjection. We endow $R\times S$ with the product topology and $S^{-1}R$ with the quotient topology.

Then, due to the continuity of the following formulas 
and their compatibility with $s_{frac}$

$((a,p),(b,q))\to (aq+bp,pq)$

$((a,p),(b,q))\to (ab,pq)$

$(a,p)\to (-a,p)$

one has that $S^{-1}R$ is automatically a topological ring and that the arrow $s_{frac}$ solves the classical universal problem in the category of topological rings.

> Q1) Is it known a way to compute the neighbourhoods of zero in $S^{-1}R$ and/or in $Frac(R)$ more explicit than the images, through $s_{frac}$, of the 
>   neighbourhoods of zero saturated by the fraction ring equivalence ?
>
> (i.e. $s(s^{-1}(s(U\times (V\cap S)))$ where $U$ is a neighbourhood of zero in $R$ and $V$ an open set.)
>
> Q2) Are there nice examples where the computation is not trivial, explicit (and good looking) ?
>
> Q3) In case $R$ has no zero divisor and with $S=R\setminus \{0\}$, in TG.III.6 Exercice 27, Bourbaki gives a sufficient condition so that the topology induced by that of $S^{-1}R=Frac(R)$ on $R$ is the given topology (that $s_{frac}$ be open). Are there other examples ?

Some facts:

- If $R$ is Hausdorff and, if $S$ contains no zero divisor, then $S^{-1}R$ is Hausdorff.

  In the case when $R$ is a topological (commutative) integral domain, setting  $S=R\setminus \{0\}$ 
  $$
  s_{frac}\ :\ R\times R'\to Frac(R)
  $$ 
  one sees that the topological ring $Frac(R)$ is automatically a topological field (due to the continuity and compatibility of $(p,q)\to (q,p)$).

Comment: The case $R=k[[x,y]]$, $k$ a field and $S^{-1}R$ is its fraction field, would be a good start ($R$ is not a neighborhood of 0 in its fraction field, if I'm correct).

Comment: Do you want S closed?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Well, I have no idea of the effect of $S$ closed. If you have some element of discussion, I would be happy to receive any ideas.

Comment: @YCor Yes, and maybe $R=k[[x]]$. In this case,  $Frac(R)=k[[x,x^{-1}]$, the field of Laurent series. Am I  right ? As $k$ is not specified, we could start with the usual ultrametric topology given by the valuation.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. The case $k[[x]]$ is clear since it is open in its fraction field $k((x))$. (Yes I thought of the standard valuation)

Comment: @YCor You note $k((x))$ the field of Laurent series ?

Comment: It might make the localisation have a slightly nicer topology...

Comment: @DavidRoberts [Do you want S closed?]---> Not necessarily. The facts I gave do not suppose $S$ closed.

Comment: yes $k((x))$ is a very standard notation for the field of Laurent series.

Comment: @YCor I wanted to be sure (many communities, many dialects, some french algebraists note $k[[x,x^{-1}]$ :). BTW, for $X$ a set of variables, I expect that $k((X))$ in general is the field of Malcev Neumann series of the free group $F(X)$ ordered by some total order. Am I right ?

Comment: Didn't know this. Anyway when I google "field laurent series" I get the notation $k((x))$ for the field of Laurent series: I just claim it's widely use, not that there is no conflicting other meaning.

Comment: There is no conflict as, for one letter $F(x)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ with the set of monomials is $\{x^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ ordered by the usual order. Then,  the Malcev Neumann series are exactly those whose support is inside some set $\{x^n\}_{n\geq N}$ (with $N\in \mathbb{Z}$) i.e. the Laurent series.

Comment: @YCor  You can have a look [there](http://www.lacim.uqam.ca/~christo/Publi%C3%A9s/1999/Malcev.pdf)

Comment: @YCor and also, for a proof, in the book of Passman, _The  algebraic  structure  of  group  rings_ (1985), theorem 2.11 p 601 ; but the notation $k((G))$ seems not yet fixed although it has widely been spread afterwards.

Comment: @YCor What is $k((x,y))$ in your language ? is it $\Big(k((y))\Big)((x))$ i.e. the field of Neumann Malcev series on $\Gamma=\{x^ky^l\}_{k,l\in \mathbb{Z}}\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2$ ordered with $x\succ y$ ?

Comment: I meant the fraction field of $k[[x,y]]$, but unlike $k((x))$ I don't claim it's standard language.

Comment: @YCor If I am correct, for the case $R=k[[x,y]]$,  the ultrametric topology is given by the valuation $$\nu(S)=inf_{w\in supp(S)}\deg(w)\in \mathbb{N}\sqcup \{+\infty\}$$ and (my partial answer below) the canonical topology (i.e. quotient by $s_{frac}$ on $k((x,y))$ is given by its unique extension $\bar{\nu}$. It induces the given topology on $k[[x,y]]$.

Comment: We can invert (formally) $s$ by taking the direct limit $\times s: R \to R$, iterated, and for arbitrary $S$ can do the same (a direct limit, directed over finite subsets of $S$, each element repeated infinitely often). Can you not put the direct limit topology on $S^{-1}R$? Of course, it's going to be weird (direct limit topologies generally are), but that's what you'd expect—consider what happens if $X$ is compact metrizable, take $R = C(X )$, and $S$ the nonzero divisors; the classical ring of quotients equals the complete ring of quotients, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and example, I must digest it. I expect that the non-zero divisors in $R=C(X)$ are exactly the set of functions such that $\mathcal{O}_f=f^{-1}(0)$ has empty interior, no ?

Comment: I think that, as the direct limit is a final topology (sorry for the possibly dated terminology but I learned it from Bourbaki), it solves the same universal problem as the one I described and then it should be the same. I must write it completely to be sure.

Comment: @DavidHandelman OK, I see the construction [there.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664471/representing-localization-as-a-direct-limit)

Comment: @DavidHandelman The direct limit being constructed, in a second step as an initial structure (see [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/what-are-the-product-and-coproduct-in-the-category-of-topological-groups)), I would not be surprised it be so, let me some time to elaborate the arrows.

Comment: For more on rings of quotients of C(X), there is a nice little monograph by Gilman, Jerison [the elder], and Lambek, mid-1960s, I think. Yes, $f^{-1}0$ having empty interior is exactly the condition for $f$ to be a non-zerodivisor (better expression than *nonzero divisor,* but I keep using the latter). Another example is $L^{\infty}(Y,\mu)$, whose classical ring of quotients (despite the algebra being non-separable in general) is its complete ring of quotients, and consists of measurable $f$ such that $\mu(f^{-1} \infty) = 0$.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Oh, I didn't know, thanks (+1)

Comment: oops, it's Fine, Gilman, and Lambek; downloadable at http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/fgl.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55725/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-david-handelman).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to (Q1) with a class of examples for (Q2) (please double-check me or ask me details if needed).

We note 
$$
i_{R}^S\ :\ R\to S^{-1}R
$$ 
the canonical map, defined by $i_{R}^S(x):=s_{frac}((x,1))$ ($i_{R}^S$ is into iff $S$ contains no annihilator).

First remark that, due to the fact that $i_{R}^S$ solves a universal problem,  if there exists some topological ring $T$ and an arrow (continuous ring morphism 
$f\ :\ R\to T$ with $f(S)\subset T^{\times}$) such that 
$f^{-1}(\mathcal{T}_T)=\mathcal{T}_R$ (the inverse image of the topology of $T$ is the exactly the given topology of $R$), then 
$$
(i_{R}^S)^{-1}(\mathcal{T}_{S^{-1}R})=\mathcal{T}_R\ .
$$
For (Q2), if the topology of $R$ is given by a *valuation* $\nu$ (in the general sense of wikipedia and Bourbaki, i.e. a mapping $\nu\ :\ R\to \Gamma\sqcup \{\infty\}$ where $\Gamma$ is some totally ordered abelian group, this includes Malcev Neumann series on $\Gamma$) then one can check that $\nu$, extended to $R\times S$ by $\nu(a,s)=\nu(a)+(-\nu(s))$, passes to quotient as an extension ($R$ has no zero divisor) of $\nu$ (call it $\bar{\nu}$) and that the topology on $S^{-1}R$ is given by $\bar{\nu}$.